# How to render a hidden window?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have an iframe (fit in a window) to load before showing it. 
When I do :

```
window.show();
window.hide();
```

The window is not hidden. "window.show()" is used to render the iframe. 
The loading of the iframe is about 10 sec.
How can I render the iframe without display the window?

My window :

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                height: '95%',
                width: '95%',
                modal: true,
                header: false,
                hideMode:'visibility',
                constrain: true,
                resizable:false,
                itemId:'winIframeItemId....',
                id:'winIframeId....',
                baseCls: 'x-window-....',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch',
                    pack: 'start'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'middle',
                        pack: 'end'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        cls: 'x-button-close-window...',
                        height: 34,
                        width: 34
                        ...
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId:'conIframeWindow',
                    layout:"fit",
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'component',
                        autoScroll: true,
                        itemId:'IframeTest',
                        baseCls: 'x-component-w....',
                        autoEl: {
                            tag: "iframe",
                            domain: '....',
                            frameborder: 0,
                            src: url
                        }
                    }]

                }]
            });
```

Comment: are you using any xtype?

Comment: Hi aviram83, I paste my code

Comment: My Two Cents, Why can't you show loading mask while the iframe is loading and hide the mask when the iframe loading is completed ? You can listen for the load event on iframe to notified when iframe load is completed.

Comment: have you try [hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-hidden) property?

Comment: The application have to be pre-loaded hidden into the window because when the user need to use the window, the application is already loaded. It's smoother and quieted for the user.

Comment: Yes but there are no render when the window is hidden and then the iframe is not pre loaded. The only solution I found is to set the X of the window to -5000 and listen the "render" event to hide the window when the iframe is loaded. It's very ugly but it works

Comment: if you are looking for another solution you may write a little fiddle so we can see how's your code looks like

Answer (score 0):

Windows and menus are typically rendered to the document body. I was able to use the Ext.Component.renderTo configuration to render windows and menus without displaying them.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5h

```
// Render a hidden window.
var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Window'
});
// Render a hidden menu.
var menu = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    menu: {
        items: [{
            text: 'Item'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    },
    text: 'Button'
});
```

Comment: What if we want to render the hidden component to some other components rather than Ext.getBody()?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan Check out the documentation for Ext.Component.renderTo. It supports rendering to any HTMLElement. Make sure you take into consideration how the display and position rules will affect where the component is rendered.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-renderTo